# Python3 - loop through list with mulitple dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

sorry I am rather a beginner when it comes to python.

I have a list like this:

```
"list": [
    {
      "id": 12345,
      "name": "test"
    },
    {
      "id": 12453,
      "value": "value1",
      "field": "test",
    }
    ]
```

When looping through several of such lists I want it to print the "name" key from the upper dictionary but only if the condition is met that "value": "value1", is present  but this is in a different dictionary.

I tried with stuff like: if 'value' in event.keys():

but I cant manage to only print this "name" key if the other condition is met. any suggestions?

Comment: Are all your list **exactly** like the one you show (i.e., exactly two elements, first one has the `name` item and the second the `value`)?

Comment: no they look quite different. and it isnt always the 2nd that has the value either unfortunately. It seems to be always the first one though that has the name key

Answer (score 0):

Below one way of doing it, it is going through all key/value of all dictionnaries so it's probably not efficient but will adapt to several possibility.
I don't know if `name` can be in the list several times, the below code will keep the last occurrence if it happens.
I made it a function so that you can use it easily on several similar lists. It returns None if the criteria was not met, the value of `name` if it was.

```py
def get_valid_name(dict_list, target_value):
    keep_name = False
    current_name = None
    for d in dict_list:
        for key, val in d.items():
            if key == "name":
                current_name = val
            elif key == "value" and val == target_value:
                keep_name = True
    return current_name if keep_name else None

for l in [original_list]:
    result = get_valid_name(l, "value1")
    if result is not None:
        print(result)
```